# Google Maps API zoom after setcenter

Tags: javascript, google-maps, zooming

I have attempted to use Google Maps to add locations to events that the user can create. As such there is an "add location" checkbox that has `onclick="initialize()"`, the map and a search box then appear with the search button having `onclick="codeAddress()"`. However the initialized map is set at zoom level 10 (as it's London as a whole) yet when someone enters an address for example, I need it to zoom to an appropriate level.

I feel as if this should be simpler that it seems. I've read alot about using `LatLngBounds()` but the examples are for more than one marker and you have to set SW and NE corners which im not sure how to calculate appropriately for different searches.

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var markersArray = [];
function initialize() {
  var locationStart = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5073346, -0.12768310000001293);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var myOptions = {
    center: locationStart,
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: locationStart,
    map: map
  });
  markersArray.push(marker);
}
// Function to remove markers
function clearOverlays() {
  if(markersArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}
// Function to search addresses and generate a list of the other options returned
function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address,
    'region' : 'uk'
  },
  function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var divTest = document.getElementById("results");
      divTest.innerHTML = "";
      if (results.length > 1) {
        $('#addressOptions').show();
        for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
          divTest.innerHTML += "<tr><td id=\"address"+ i + "\" onclick=\"grabLocation(" + i + ")\" >" + results[i].formatted_address + "</td></tr>";
        };
      } else {
        $('#addressOptions').hide();
      }
      divTest.innerHTML += "";
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        'map' : map,
        'position' : results[0].geometry.location,
        'preserveViewport' : false
      });
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      markersArray.push(marker);
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Apologies if this is a simple question, I've been looking around for a simple answer for a while now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geocoder returns a suggested viewport

```
results[0].geometry.viewport
```

It can be used to zoom to a level that makes sense for the result returned

[Example](http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2stateSelectList.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
// modified from http://www.weltmeer.ch/divelog/
// globals
var map = null;
var geocoder = null;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.288828765662416, 7.945261001586914),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  findAddress("United States");
}

function findAddress(address) {
  var addressStr = document.getElementById("stateselect").value;
  if (!address && (addressStr != ''))
    address = "State of " + addressStr;
  else
    address = addressStr;
  if ((address != '') && geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          if (results && results[0] &&
            results[0].geometry && results[0].geometry.viewport)
            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#map_canvas {
  height: 90%;
}

#TOPNAV {
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <title>Zoom to State with Select List (Google Maps API)</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="TOPNAV">
    <select id="stateselect" name="countryselect" class="textfeld" onclick="findAddress();return false" onchange="findAddress();return false" onfocus="">
      <option value=''>Select a State....</option>
      <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
      <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
      <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
      <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
      <option value="California">California</option>
      <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
      <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
      <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
      <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
      <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
      <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
      <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
      <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
      <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
      <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
      <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
      <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
      <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
      <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
      <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
      <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
      <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
      <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
      <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
      <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
      <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
      <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
      <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
      <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
      <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
      <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
      <option value="New York">New York</option>
      <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
      <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
      <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
      <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
      <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
      <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
      <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
      <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
      <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
      <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
      <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
      <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
      <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
      <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
      <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
      <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
      <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
      <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>

</html>
```