# How to find the boundary points with center and zoom level given?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The `LatLngBounds` function needs the corner points!

How to find the boundary points with center and zoom level given?
Is there Google API V3 which achieves this?

Or can this be done someway with the static maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the geocoder, it returns a suggested viewort (that is a google.maps.LatLngBounds() object).

See this similar question:
[Google Maps API zoom after setcenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161203/google-maps-api-zoom-after-setcenter)

If you only have the center coordinates and the zoom, use them to initialize the map, listen for the bounds_changed event, then use the map.getBounds() function.

All of the above are described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the boundary points of the visible map? If so, you can use the getBounds method of the map object.

```
var llb = map.getBounds();
```

Comment: I mean to find the boundary points "online" through the API. Did you mean the same?